# Laravel - Query to mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am new to Laravel. I have a existing and working query that allow me to get all the item present in my Mysql Table.
File --> ProductRepostitory.php

```
Public function getAll(){
        $data = Product::paginate(10);
        if(empty($data)){
            return false;
        }else{
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

In that table I have a column named PR_ACTIF --> 1 or 0.
I would like to display in the query only PR_ACTIF = 1
Thanks for you help!

Comment: You need a `foreach` loop to get the column data

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
...
Public function getAll(){
    $data = Product::where('PR_ACTIF', 1)->paginate(10);
    if(empty($data)){
        return false;
    }else{
        return $data;
    }
}
...
```

Comment: That was a fast an esay one :-D Tks working perfectly!